# URL Redirect with https

Tags: apache, url, https, redirect

I have the following code in my httpd.conf file and that is redirecting all requests to www.example.com/signup correctly to the secure location

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect permanent /signup https://www.example.com/signup.html
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I get '/signup page not found' error if someone types in the URL

https://www/example.com/signup

Is there any rule I can add to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to resolve it, but since you are getting the error on the https:// virtual host, you need to show the setup for that. This is the http:// setup which is working as you say.

Comment: I added the line "Redirect permanent /signup https://www.example.com/signup.html"  in <VirtualHost *:443> in ssl.conf file and that works.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line in VirtualHost *:443 in ssl.conf file and it works now:

Redirect permanent /signup https://www.example.com/signup.html